# Echo a mysql column by php as an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i want to fetch a mysql table named "my_table" column named "Email" contents as an array by php , so this is my code :

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "my_table";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table");

    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }

    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data[] = $row['Email'];
    }
    echo join($data, ',');
?>
```

but this code returns me this error :
No database selected

but i've selected my table and database ...

and i know this code have some problems as mixing mysql and mysqli content but i dont know how to fix it i just want that array echo , if this code need to be fixed just guid me , 
 how to solve this problem ? thanks in advance
Thanks to @Martin 
my problem has solved i just changed the code by this way :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = ""; $dbname = "my_db"; 
// Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); // Check connection 
if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM my_table");
if($result === FALSE) { 
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}


$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$data[] = $row['Email'];
}
echo join($data, ',')
?>
```

Comment: mixing `mysql with mysqli` in your code!!

Comment: so how to fix that :(

Comment: mysql_query should be updated to mysqli_query

Comment: And also you have to pass connection string through mysqli_query.

Comment: i want to change this codes tu my_sql i think this is better

Answer (score -2):

You are conencting to a database here called "my_table":

```
$dbname = "my_table";
```

And then, in your SQL statement, you try connecting to a table called the same:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table");
```

Are you sure this is the correct name for your database?

On PHPMyAdmin you can click "Databases" to view the Database names and then, when clicking on the db, it will give you a list of tables:

[Image file of getting database views from tables in PHPMyAdmin](http://webvaultwiki.com.au/%28S%28iungfwenvz2f5c55pioeinil%29%29/GetFile.aspx?File=/images/screenshots/mysql/phpmyadmin02.png)

Comment: i've changed my db name but it's still returns the same error :(

Comment: Can you paste the error message?

Comment: No database selected

Comment: Try this, obviously ensuring the correct database name is in place:

<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "DBNAME";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

?>

Comment: still same error ...

Comment: @SajadAsadi are you using MySQLi *and* MySQL? If you connect via MySQLi this will not be available to MySQL and vice versa.

Comment: Instead use this: `mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM my_table");`

Comment: WoW 
Thanks so much martin thanks <3
@Martin

Comment: @SajadAsadi all you need is to do this sort of update to all of your MySQL_ function references to use the newer MySQLi references, although you should be using OOP approach but that requires more in depth rewriting. Glad to help :)